# Spyder Refreshing Variable Explorer from within the IPython console

Tags: python, variables, refresh, spyder, explorer

Is it possible to "click" the refresh button on the variable explorer using some function within the IPython console in Spyder? I wanted the explorer to refresh when a certain condition was met. This naturally leads to the broader question: is it possible to interact with the Spyder IDE within the IPython console?